# How to add class on a clicked li and remove old class form anywhere of the li in vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I did it using jquery inside vue method. But I still want a vue js solution. 
I want to remove the class from the li and then add the same class on the clicked li. So here is what I did using jquery plus vue

```
<ul class="manage-link">
    <li class="current 1" @click="run(1,'In progress')">Awaiting approval</li>
    <li class="2" @click="run(2,'In progress')">In progress</li>
    <li class="3" @click="run(3,'Completed')">Completed</li>
    <li class="4" @click="run(4,'Shipped')">Shipped</li>
    <li class="5" @click="run(5,'Delivered')">Delivered</li>
    <li class="6" @click="run(6,'Cancelled')">Cancelled</li>
    <li class="7" @click="run(7,'Under review')">Under review</li>
    <li class="pointer"></li>

</ul>

 methods: {
        run(num, str){
            console.log('ok');
            $(".manage-link>li").removeClass("current");
            $('.'+num).addClass('current');
        }
    }
```

Here `str` is for another task. Not related to this problem. This is working just fine but I want to achieve same thing using only vue js. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super easy using [class bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-HTML-Classes)

```
<li class="1" :class="{current: current == 1}" @click="run(1)">Awaiting approval</li>
<li class="2" :class="{current: current == 2}" @click="run(2)">In Progress</li>
<li class="3" :class="{current: current == 3}" @click="run(3)">Completed</li>
<!-- and so on -->
```

---

```
data () { // or just "data:" if this is not a component
  return {
    current: 1
  }
},
methods: {
  run(num) {
    this.current = num
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice and easy solution. Didn't think this way. One thing remove the first `class` from your answer. Two `class` is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `$event` object in your click handler and then handle the class manipulation there like this:

```
<ul class="manage-link">
    <li class="current 1" @click="run($event, 1,'In progress')">Awaiting approval</li>
    <li class="2" @click="run($event, 2,'In progress')">In progress</li>
    <li class="3" @click="run($event, 3,'Completed')">Completed</li>
    <li class="4" @click="run($event, 4,'Shipped')">Shipped</li>
    <li class="5" @click="run($event, 5,'Delivered')">Delivered</li>
    <li class="6" @click="run($event, 6,'Cancelled')">Cancelled</li>
    <li class="7" @click="run($event, 7,'Under review')">Under review</li>
    <li class="pointer"></li>

</ul>

 methods: {
    run(ev, num, str){
        console.log('ok');
        [].slice.call(ev.target.parentNode.children).forEach(function(child) {
            child.classList.remove('current');
        });
        ev.target.classList.add('current');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $index to save active element.
such as

```js
<ul>
  <li 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
<ul class="manage-link">
    <li class="current 1" :class="{ active ? activeIndex === 1 }"@click="run(1,'In progress')">Awaiting approval</li>
    <li class="2"  :class="{ active ? activeIndex === 2 } @click="run(2,'In progress')">In progress</li>
    <li class="3" :class="{ active ? activeIndex === 3 } @click="run(3,'Completed')">Completed</li>
    <li class="4" :class="{ active ? activeIndex === 4 } @click="run(4,'Shipped')">Shipped</li>
    <li class="5" :class="{ active ? activeIndex === 5 } @click="run(5,'Delivered')">Delivered</li>
    <li class="6" :class="{ active ? activeIndex === 6 } @click="run(6,'Cancelled')">Cancelled</li>
    <li class="7" :class="{ active ? activeIndex === 7 } @click="run(7,'Under review')">Under review</li>
    <li class="pointer"></li>

</ul>

 data: {
  return {
    activeIndex: -1,
  };
 },
 methods: {
        run(num, str){
            this.activeIndex = num;
        }
    }
```

```
</ul>
```